# Pass only specific types as argument to function

Tags: swift

I have a function which is being repeated about 8-9 times and I'm trying to cut down on redundancy.Is it possible to create a function which take spefic types and returns an array of the initlizated type using the json object being sent.

**Current function**

```
   static func initArray(json: JSON)-> [Event]{
        var array = [Event]()
        json.forEach(){
            array.append(Event.init(json: $0.1))
        }
        return array
    }
```

**Desired function**

```
static func initArray<T> (type: T, json: JSON)-> [T]{
    var array = [T]()
    //I get stuck here im not too sure how to initlize the type
    //Thats why im wondering if it's possible to pass speific types
    //to the function
    return array
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize an instance of `T` just like an instance of any known class, with whatever initializers are available to it.  To know what your options are, you generally need to constraint `T` in some form.  The way I typically go about this is to define a `protocol` that all the types I care about passing to the function adopt.  In your case you would put specific initializers in your `protocol`.  Then constraint `T` to be of that type:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    init(json: JSON)
}

class someClass {
    static func initArray<T:SomeProtocol>(type: T, json: JSON) -> [T] {
        // Create your objects, I'll create one as an example
        let instance = T.init(json: json)

        return [instance]
    }
}
```

Constraining generic types can be more complex than what I've shown, so I'd recommend checking out the [Type Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID186) section of the [Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) chapter of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) for more information.